# How to call div content in widows.open()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Actually i have a asp:LinkButton in aspx page and i just want that whenever user clicks on asp:LinkButton open popup on dat asp:LinkButton its already done and i have given another link to it(its ur website's link only) and its working fine,
but the problem is now i want to open a popup with checkboxes with the cities name.

i have made one type of you can say block in a DIV on the same aspx page in the bottom and now i want is to call this div content in the script above in windows.open..

Please help me out ..
asap

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can't show only piece of the current page using the window.open function - only the whole page.
Use ModulPopup from the AjaxControlToolkit or Dialog from the jQuery-UI or some similar functionality. 
Or you can create new page that will contain only div with cities names checkboxes and open it via the window.open function